# CGI::param called in list context and Undefined subroutine &CGI::Plus::randword called errors

Tags: perl, cgi

I am trying to dockerize a web application which is in perl and at the end it connects with MariaDB via Apache.
I already have a database setup. My containers are running but the problem is with perl scripts; they are not running. Also, one module called CGI PLUS is having problem while installation. Can someone have a look in following text and let me know what can be the possible issue here and also share the solution to rectify it?

```
################################################################
#Perl modules
Install the required Perl modules.

cpan CGI
cpan CGI::Plus
cpan CGI::Session
cpan DBI
cpan Crypt::Eksblowfish::Bcrypt
cpan File::Basename
cpan Auth::Yubikey_WebClient
cpan Tie::IxHash
cpan Apache::Solr
cpan HTML::Entities
cpan WWW::CSRF
cpan Crypt::Random
cpan LWP::Simple
cpan Text::NSP::Measures::2D::Fisher::twotailed
cpan XML::Simple
cpan Statistics::R
cpan Cache::FileCache
cpan Digest::MD5
cpan Date::Calc
cpan Data::Dumper
cpan Text::ParseWords
cpan Cwd
cpan Log::Log4perl
#Tests of the module XML:DOM::XPath fail because they use a deprecated syntax but the module is OK
# Install with the following command
perl -MCPAN -e "CPAN::Shell->notest('install', 'XML::DOM::XPath')";
cpan Bio::DB::Fasta
cpan Log::Dispatch::File

################################################################
# Apache

Set up an Apache server with ssl enabled.
Enable the following modules
enable session
session_cookie
rewrite
RewriteEngine
ssl

Generate a dummy certificate only for a test server.
Call the script /usr/bin/gensslcert.

Add the following lines to vhost-ssl.conf
Header always set X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff"
Header always set X-Xss-Protection "1; mode=block"
Header always set X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN"
Header set Content-Security-Policy "default-src https: 'unsafe-eval' 'u
```

Following is the error log generated after making attempt to install CGI PLUS.

```
5.066 CGI::param called in list context from t/test.t line 96, this can lead to vulnerabilities. See the warning in "Fetching the value or values of a single named parameter" at /usr/local/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.38.0/CGI.pm line 415. 
5.066 Undefined subroutine &CGI::Plus::randword called at /root/.cpan/build/CGI-Plus-0.15-0/blib/lib/CGI/Plus.pm line 644. 
5.066 # Looks like your test exited with 255 just after 4. 5.068 t/test.t ..
5.068 Dubious, test returned 255 (wstat 65280, 0xff00) 5.068 Failed
33/37 subtests
```

Please also let me know if you require any further information to understand the complete scenario. Following is my docker file to show how I am trying to run the perl scripts. Can you find any issue or problem in it?

```
# Use the latest Perl image as the base
FROM perl:latest

# Install system dependencies
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    apache2 \
    && apt-get clean \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /tmp/* /var/tmp/*


#Install the required Perl modules
RUN cpan CGI
RUN cpan App::cpanminus
RUN cpan CPAN::DistnameInfo

#Install libcgi-pm-perl using apt-get
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y libcgi-pm-perl


#Install the required Perl modules
RUN cpan CGI::Safe
RUN cpan String::Util

#RUN cpan CGI::Plus
RUN cpan -T CGI::Plus


RUN cpan CGI::Session
RUN cpan DBI
RUN cpan Crypt::Eksblowfish::Bcrypt
RUN cpan File::Basename
RUN cpan Auth::Yubikey_WebClient
RUN cpan Tie::IxHash
RUN cpan Apache::Solr
RUN cpan HTML::Entities
RUN cpan WWW::CSRF
RUN cpan Crypt::Random
RUN cpan LWP::Simple
RUN cpan Text::NSP::Measures::2D::Fisher::twotailed
RUN cpan XML::Simple
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y r-base
RUN cpan Statistics::R
RUN cpan Cache::FileCache
RUN cpan Digest::MD5
RUN cpan Date::Calc
RUN cpan Data::Dumper
RUN cpan Text::ParseWords
RUN cpan Cwd
RUN cpan Log::Log4perl

# Install XML::DOM::XPath without testing
RUN perl -MCPAN -e "CPAN::Shell->notest('install', 'XML::DOM::XPath')"

# Install Bio::DB::Fasta
RUN cpan Bio::DB::Fasta

#Install Log::Dispatch::File
RUN cpan Log::Dispatch::File

# Copy your Perl web application files to the Apache document root
COPY ./cgi-bin /var/www/html/cgi-bin
COPY ./css_js /var/www/html/css_js

#COPY ./cgi-bin /srv/www/cgi-bin/mysql/.
#COPY  ./srv/www/htdocs/cal /srv/www/htdocs/cal
#COPY ./srv/www/htdocs/DataTables-1.10.22/ srv/www/htdocs/DataTables-1.10.22
#COPY ./cal/img  /srv/www/htdocs/gif

# Copy your custom virtual host configuration into the container
#COPY custom-vhost.conf /etc/apache2/sites-available/

# Set permissions for Apache user (www-data) to access the application files
#RUN chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/html/

#Enable your custom virtual host:
#RUN a2ensite custom-vhost

# Enable CGI execution and set the handler for .cgi and .pl files
RUN sed -i 's/Options Indexes FollowSymLinks/Options Indexes FollowSymLinks ExecCGI/' /etc/apache2/apache2.conf
RUN echo 'AddHandler cgi-script .cgi .pl' >> /etc/apache2/apache2.conf

#Enable perl files 
#RUN a2enmod cgid

# Set the executable permission on Perl scripts
#RUN chmod +x /var/www/html/cgi-bin/*.pl

# Set the executable permission on Perl scripts in the cgi-bin directory and its subdirectories
RUN find /var/www/html/cgi-bin -type f -name "*.pl" -exec chmod +x {} \;

# Expose port 80 for Apache
EXPOSE 80

# Start Apache web server
CMD ["/usr/sbin/apache2ctl", "-D", "FOREGROUND"]

# Make all .pl files executable in the cgi-bin directory and its subdirectories
#RUN find /srv/www/cgi-bin/mysql/. -type f -name "*.pl" -exec chmod +x {} \;
```

When I run .pl script, it gives something like this:

```
# perl admin.pl
Status: 500
Content-type: text/html

<h1>Software error:</h1>
<pre>Undefined subroutine &CGI::Plus::randword called at
/usr/local/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.38.0/CGI/Plus.pm line 644.
</pre>
<p>
For help, please send mail to this site's webmaster, giving this error message
and the time and date of the error.

</p>
[Wed Sep 13 16:14:24 2023] admin.pl: Undefined subroutine
&CGI::Plus::randword called at
/usr/local/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.38.0/CGI/Plus.pm line 644.
```

Answer (score 6):

Looking at the [source code](https://metacpan.org/dist/CGI-Plus/source/lib/CGI/Plus.pm#L644) you can see it does, indeed, try to use `randword` a sub that it doesn't define itself.

Scrolling up to [the top](https://metacpan.org/dist/CGI-Plus/source/lib/CGI/Plus.pm#L6), it's a sub with a name that makes it sound like something `use String::Util ':all';` might be expected to provide.

There's no sign of `randword` in [the source of that module](https://metacpan.org/module/String::Util/source) so let's look at [the Changelog](https://metacpan.org/release/BAKERSCOT/String-Util-1.34/source/Changes):

> 1.33  2023-01-31
>
> - Remove a bunch of old deprecated functions: crunch, cellfill, define, randword, fullchomp, randcrypt, equndef, neundef

Going back to CGI::Plus, and looking at [its installer](https://metacpan.org/release/MIKO/CGI-Plus-0.15/source/Build.PL#L13):

> ```
> 'String::Util' => '1.24'
> ```

So it [states](https://metacpan.org/dist/Module-Build/view/lib/Module/Build/Authoring.pod#Format-of-prerequisites) that it needs String::Util 1.24 or higher, but this is wrong since it needs a version that is *less* that 1.33.

---

You could:

- Patch CGI::Plus locally to either:

  - correct the error in the Build.PL *or*
  - replace the call to `randword` with something else
- Submit a bug report to the author and ask them to fix it (although I wouldn't hold out too much hope as the module hasn't seen an update in almost a decade and this bug has existed for over half a year) … oh wait [someone did that 7 months ago and has been ignored](https://rt.cpan.org/Public/Bug/Display.html?id=146235)
- Replace CGI::Plus with something else (which might be a wise given the lack of on going support (it looks like the author has been [inactive on CPAN](https://metacpan.org/author/MIKO?sort=%5B%5B3,1%5D%5D) since 2016)).

Comment: Probably. Have you tried it? (I still strongly recommend replacing the unsupported module entirely though).

Comment: Thank you for the valuable feedback. Please confirm if I can modify the local **Build.pl** file (located in the directory **root/.cpan/buid/cgi-plus0.15-0)** manually just by entering 'String::Util' => '1.32' instead of 'String::Util' => '1.24'. Please also suggest what and how can I replace the call to **randword** with something else because I am unable to find **Plus.pm** file in the directory **/usr/local/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.38.0/CGI/Plus.pm**

Comment: Please also confirm with what and how can I replace the unsupported module entirely?

Comment: I can’t recommend an alternative to a tool when I don’t know what you’re using it for in the first place.

Comment: Here is a part of the script where CGI::PLUS is:
`use strict;`
`BEGIN {require './Snv.pm';}`
`use WWW::CSRF qw(generate_csrf_token check_csrf_token CSRF_OK);`
`my $cgi = new CGI::Plus;`
`$cgi->csrf(1);`
`my $ref = $cgi->Vars;`
`my $snv = new Snv;`
`my %options = ('MaxAge' => 10800); #for WWW::CSRF 3 hours, same as session cookie`
`#$ref = $snv->htmlencodehash($ref);`
`my ($dbh) = "";`
`my $item = "";`
`my $value = "";`
`my %logins = ();`
`open(IN, "/srv/tools/textreadonly.txt");`
`while (<IN>){chomp;($item,$value)=split(/\:/);$logins{$item}=$value;}`
`close IN;`

Comment: If I try without CGI::PLUS, this error: **Can't locate CGI/Plus.pm in @INC (you may need to install the CGI::Plus module) (@INC entries checked: /usr/local/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.38.0/aarch64-linux-gnu /usr/local/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.38.0 /usr/local/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.38.0/aarch64-linux-gnu /usr/local/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.38.0 /usr/local/lib/perl5/5.38.0/aarch64-linux-gnu /usr/local/lib/perl5/5.38.0) at ./Snv.pm line 364.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at ./Snv.pm line 364.
Compilation failed in require at help.pl line 8.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at help.pl line 8.**

Answer (score 1):

> CGI::param called in list context

It's always a good idea to read the documentation for any module that you're using. The [documentation for CGI](https://metacpan.org/dist/CGI/view/lib/CGI.pod) includes a section entitled [Fetching the value or values of a single named parameter](https://metacpan.org/dist/CGI/view/lib/CGI.pod#Fetching-the-value-or-values-of-a-single-named-parameter) which contains this:

> **Warning** - calling param() in list context can lead to vulnerabilities if you do not sanitise user input as it is possible to inject other param keys and values into your code. This is why the multi_param() method exists, to make it clear that a list is being returned, note that param() can still be called in list context and will return a list for back compatibility.
>
> The following code is an example of a vulnerability as the call to param will be evaluated in list context and thus possibly inject extra keys and values into the hash:
>
> ```
> my %user_info = (
>     id   => 1,
>     name => $q->param('name'),
> );
> ```
>
> The fix for the above is to force scalar context on the call to ->param by prefixing it with "scalar"
>
> ```
> name => scalar $q->param('name'),
> ```
>
> If you call param() in list context with an argument a warning will be raised
> by CGI.pm, you can disable this warning by setting $CGI::LIST_CONTEXT_WARN to 0 or by using the multi_param() method instead
>
> If a value is not given in the query string, as in the queries "name1=&name2=", it will be returned as an empty string.
>
> If the parameter does not exist at all, then param() will return undef in scalar context, and the empty list in a list context.